# Projects dependency configuration file generation via Helm with Azure Dev Spaces and Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

The projects below seems using Helm to define projects dependency on file requirements.yaml below, and azds.yaml and Chart project for each project.

https://github.com/Azure/dev-spaces/blob/master/samples/BikeSharingApp/charts/requirements.yaml
https://github.com/Azure/dev-spaces/tree/master/samples/BikeSharingApp/charts

My questions are:
1 Is my understanding above correct?

2 Is the whole folder, charts, above generated manually or via tool?

https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-team-development

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: I cannot find a solution. A similar ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124873/helm-install-failed-with-projects-that-has-project-dependency?noredirect=1#comment101152302_57124873